# Is there is any way to run the two executable files at a time at one screen by splitting screen in windows Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

Have a parent application  that enables you to run 2 different applications in 2 windows. So for example have Teams app in right hand window and another exe/app in the left hand window

please give me any possible way to do achieve this requirement or is it doable or not

Comment: Could you please post it to [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand what you mean fully, but it sounds like FancyZones, part of the Windows PowerToys tools, could help - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/fancyzones

Comment: I need this functionality by splitting the windows forms. One frame running Microsoft teams and other frame running .exe application.  I think powerToy is the windows operation system tool that you can organize the application manually in to Fancyzone by the users